# Visual Studio Code me genera un archivo .history

Tags: visual, extensiones

Tengo un problema con visual studio code. El problema es que al generar un cambio a cualquier programa, este me crea un archivo ".history". Dentro de este se encuentra los cambios que hice. Yo lo quiero sacar por que me molesta y algunas veces cuando quiero buscar palabras claves me aparecen tambien lo que estan dentro de ese history.
Busque por google y no encontre nada relacionado a esto.
Dejo una foto del archivo que me genera
Tambien busque en extensiones si tengo alguna extension con nombre de history y no tengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizas esta pregunta te ayude https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446901/how-can-i-see-local-history-changes-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: es una extensión para guardar el histórico de cambios, deberías de deshabilitar tus plugins e irlos habilitando uno por uno, porque no recuerdo cual era en especifico